# How to get caller id from usb modem serial port on First or second call

Tags: c#, call, mode

I know this is old question. I have read all solution and it's work but not well. Sometimes it's shows the caller id and sometimes not. Only shows ring.Is there any way to ensure to get caller id every time.here is the code currently I am using

```
 public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetModem();

}


public void SetModem()
{
    sp = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
    this.sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);
    sp.Open();
}

void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        string x = sp.ReadLine(); // will read to the first carriage return
        this.BeginInvoke(new SetTextDeleg(si_DataReceived), new object[] { x });
    }
    catch
    { }
}

private void si_DataReceived(string data)
{
    dataReceived = data.Trim();
    richTextBoxEx1.Text = dataReceived;
    // Do whatever with the data that is coming in.
}
```

}
}

Comment: Maybe if you install serial port monitoring software, Then with regard to monitoring the data sent you can get a good result.

Comment: Thanks. I am using https://sambapos.com/ . it's working caller id well. but in my code it's not working for all time. Why my code could not get the caller details. It's only showing ring like non caller id modem. I have a non caller id support modem. When I use that modem it's shows only RING. But in my caller id supported modem it's also showing same. I saw it's work for some time. but the caller id showed after 4 ring.